# BLE : How can i create my own base UUID and alias

Tags: uuid, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I know i can create my own service with BLE by using a 128 bit UUID using a too like *uuidgen* on Mac.
But i'm really confused with the way to define an alias and a base UUID for my service.
Indeed, a base UUID need to get the form of:

```
0x0000xxxx-1213-XYZA-1523-781FEABCD123
```

and the alias

```
Service 0x1523 : 0x00001523-1213-XYZA-1523-781FEABCD123
characteristic 0x1524 : 0x00001524-1213-XYZA-1523-781FEABCD123
```

But when i generate a uuid i get something like:

```
580663F1-AFF1-457F-9F79-0F2BF3E11892
```

How can i specify the alias in order to identify the Service and the characteristics ? Do i need to remove the first part ?
Or am i completly wrong and do i need to do something else to get them ?

How do i managed to generate a base UUID like the Bluetooth SIG one ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are free to define your UUID for your service, you don't need to follow the format you mentioned. If you use 16bit UUID, it will be extended to BLE base uuid. See below question:

[What range of Bluetooth UUIDs can be used for vendor defined profiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243769/what-range-of-bluetooth-uuids-can-be-used-for-vendor-defined-profiles)

For reference, you can see inside bluez's source tree, plugins/gatt-example.c. For weight service, they are using arbitrary 128-bit UUID. See register_weight_service():

https://github.com/aguedes/bluez/blob/master/plugins/gatt-example.c

Here is the service on the run, connected with gatttool (bluez tool):

attr handle: 0x003c, end grp handle: 0x0040 uuid: 00001806-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x0041, end grp handle: 0x0049 uuid: 0000180e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x004a, end grp handle: 0x0056 uuid: 00001811-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x0057, end grp handle: 0x005b uuid: 0000a0f0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0xfffa, end grp handle: 0xfffe uuid: feee74dc-a8de-3196-1149-d43596c00a4f

And the characteristics starting from handle 0xfffa:

handle: 0xfffa, uuid: 2800
handle: 0xfffb, uuid: 2802
handle: 0xfffc, uuid: 2803
handle: 0xfffd, uuid: e9258c1e-8962-c4b6-0b45-2c9018f28880
handle: 0xfffe, uuid: 2904
handle: 0xffff, uuid: 2901

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if i get it right, i could use completely different uuid for the service and the characteristics ? The format i provided is based on the documentation of Nordic and i find this approach clean since we can cleary see the relations between the service and the characteritics. I add some details in my question

Comment: Yes, since it's free to define, you can use completely different uuids, and also fine with the format you mentioned too.

Comment: Ok thanks ! One last question, if i define my own uuid with the uuidgen command and rewrite the first part, would it still be unique or can i get come collision with another provider ?

Comment: Although it is very unlikely to have a collision among 128-bit uuids which is randomly generated, you can't be sure. Unless you want to register your generated uuid to bluetooth SIG as yours.