# Why BLE service UUid are different in android and iphone?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, bluetooth-gatt

I'm using [`noble`](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/noble) in my app, which scans for BLE devices. The issue is, the Service UUId in BLE GATT that I receive in my android is the longer UUID (i.e. 00002220000001000800000805f9b34fb), whereas in Iphone I get (2220).

I need my android to have 2220 because that's the platform I require. Is there a way to get the latter service UUID? Although, they're both the same, look at the longer one, "2220" is present from bit position 4 from left to right.

Answer (score 2):

They are the same. A 128-bit uuid is derived from the 16-bit uuid. See [What range of Bluetooth UUIDs can be used for vendor defined profiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243769/what-range-of-bluetooth-uuids-can-be-used-for-vendor-defined-profiles).