# send/receive string via GATT in BLE

Tags: c, bluetooth-lowenergy, termios, bluetooth-gatt

I have been successfully sending and receiving hexa values via GATT using "[Heart rate service](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services)" and with characteristic "[Heart Rate Measurement](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/characteristics)". Now I need to send TX/RX strings over GATT. Can anyone help me out by giving suggestion about:

1. Which service should I use to send string?
2. Which characteristic should I use?
3. If not possible by predefined services, what should I do?

I need to send some characters from server side. The data should be received by the client for every instance of time.

Comment: There is no standardized service and characteristic for a serial protocol. Just choose one that is not assigned to a specific purpose. Write to the characteristic to send data to the peripheral; subscribe to updates to receive data from the peripheral. It's the same as for the heart rate measurement - except you also write to the characteristic.

Comment: My doubt is to chose which one?. Because I didn't got clear data from internet. Which service and which characteristics is suitable for it ?

Comment: You can easily define a custom one for your needs.

Comment: The rule is to use a 128-bit UUID (and not a 16 or 32 bit one). See http://www.cypress.com/forum/psoc-4-ble/how-can-i-get-uuid-services-and-characteristics or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243769/what-range-of-bluetooth-uuids-can-be-used-for-vendor-defined-profiles.

Comment: At least let us know what the device is you are using as server.  
You can also use an app like nRF Connect to find your device and explore all the services and their characteristics.  
Best options are the characteristics capable of read,
write and notify.

Comment: I am using a device, named as nina-B1 BLE module. I have set it as a server. Another mobile app(BLE tool) is using as both server and client. Another NINA-B1 also acting as server and client(simultaneously). I need to know the name of characteristics @Groover

Comment: Yes, We can define custom and use 128 bit UUID. As I am a fresher, I don't know how to define the custom services. If possible help me out with some links..        -Thanks 4 ur help.